# Get moving mean in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am having a spark data frame with several columns. I have to get moving average and moving standard deviation for a particular column and append it to the data frame.

As an example :

```
col1   col2

1       5

1       10

1       15
```

and If my window for moving  mean is 2 then my df need to be look like :

```
col1     col2     mean
1        5        5
1        10       7.5
1        15       12.5
```

I have found one way i.e to convert it into pandas dataframe, use their function for this.

But I want to do it in pyspark dataframe as my data can be very large.